# Target a custom attribute within a div

Tags: css, attributes

I have a set of divs with a number sequence. How can I access a specific number (eg. si=3)

I've tried a few options with no joy. Any other options?

```
<div id="parentdiv" style="height:500px;>
    <div class="child_div" si="1" title="F1" style="top:360px; left:68px;"></div>
    <div class="child_div" si="2" title="F1" style="top:360px; left:80px;"></div>
    </div>

    ATTEMPTS

    #parentdiv si[2] {
       left:50%;
    }

    #parentdiv > [si~="2"]  {
      left:50%;
    }

    #parentdiv > div[si~="2"]  {
      left:50%;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `#parentdiv > [si="2"]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly. this `#parentdiv [si="2"]` does work **but** position values such as top and left need to have a positioning context.

In this case, the element need to have either `position:absolute` or `position:relative` (depending on your requirement) for the position values to work.

Secondly, the *inline* style will take effect **last** and so override any linked CSS styles **unless** additional specificity is applied.

Unfortunately, the only way to override an *inline style* is with `!important`.

```css
#parentdiv * {
  position: relative;
}
#parentdiv [si="1"] {
  height: 50px;
  background: orange;
}
#parentdiv [si="2"] {
  height: 50px;
  background: pink;
  left: 50% !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="parentdiv" style="height:500px;">
  <div class="child_div" si="1" title="F1" style="top:60px; left:68px;">1</div>
  <div class="child_div" si="2" title="F1" style="top:60px; left:80px;">2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
 div[si="2"]  {
        left:50%;
    }

<div id="parentdiv" style="height:500px;">
    <div class="child_div" si="1" title="F1" style="">si_1</div>
    <div class="child_div" si="2" title="F1" style="">si_2</div>
    </div>
```